# App is running wrong on iOS 7.1(screen size)

Tags: ios, xcode7

When I run the app on iOS 7.1, I have a problem with screen size. On iOS 7.1 it is smaller than it should be(between black spaces). Where to move to find the error? Thanks.

Here is the screenshots:

iOS 7.1:[image: ios 7.1]

iOS 9.1:[image: ios 9.1]

Comment: You need the proper launch images. A launch screen storyboard is only for iOS 8.0 and later.

Comment: Just provide launch image properly after your problem solve...that's it.

Comment: even if i am not using a launch screen storyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have setup a launch screen storyboard, you need to realize that it will only be used on devices with iOS 8.0 or later. For older versions of iOS, you still need to provide all of the appropriate launch images.

Comment: even if i am not using a launch screen storyboard?

Comment: If you are not using a launch screen then you need all of the appropriate launch images for all versions of iOS that your app supports.